# How to slice elements from 2nd item in a c# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, slice

Given a 1D array,

```
double[] arr = { 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1 };
```

I want to get values from 2nd index till last and want to store the array in a variable.
Want to get something like this:

```
new_arr = {3, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1 }; //first element sliced
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C# 8 [indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) feature

```cs
double[] arr = { 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1 };
var slice = arr[1..];
```

It'll return all items from index 1 till the end of array and give you an expected slice `{3, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1 }`. Again, it works only with C# 8 and .NET Core 3.x.

For earliest versions of C# you should do this by yourself, using `Array.Copy` for example or `System.Linq`

```cs
double[] arr = { 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1 };
var slice = arr.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 8, you can use [Indices & Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges). It goes something like this:

```
var newArray = oldArray[1..];  // Takes everything from index 1 until the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to skip the fist item and take the rest. This will give you the sequence:

```
arr.Skip(1);
```

Which you can convert to a new array like this:

```
var new_arr = arr.Skip(1).ToArray();
```